How to diagnose hanging git push?
I've been working on a project for a couple of weeks, using GitHub as the remote repo. Today, I suddenly can no longer push to remote. It's now hanging indefinitely.
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 105, done.
Counting objects: 100% (105/105), done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Writing objects: 100% (95/95), 8.87 KiB | 8.87 MiB/s, done.
Total 95 (delta 77), reused 85 (delta 67), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (77/77), completed with 10 local objects.

I've tried git gc, reinstalling git, cloning into a new directory and trying to push a different commit from there, and no joy.
I'm using git 2.34.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS via Windows Subsystem for Linux.
How can I get more information about the internals of the git push process to diagnose the issue?

This question is similar to: Git push hangs when pushing to Github?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try strace git push.

Start with setting environment variable GIT_TRACE. See examples at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22GIT_TRACE%22

I would recommend first to upgrade Git (ppa update).
Then you can set TRACE2, as I did here
GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1 git push
# or
GIT_TRACE2=1 git push

See if that gives you any clue when the process stalls.
